# Can't connect to local database in SQL Server Management Studio 2017

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am trying to use SQL Server Management Studio 2017 with local database. 
When i try to connect to local database i get this

[image: error]

I installed SQL Server Management Studio from this link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017

I was searching the web for solution but i haven't found it yet.
When i open SQL server configuration manager

[image: this]

is what i see.

I also tried using different server names but i haven't had much luck with that.
Maybe i need to install some additional software?

Comment: Clearly you have not installed SQL Server. :) SSMS is not SQL Server; it is (as it's name suggests) a Management Tool for SQL Server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please Install SQL Server.

Your problem will get solved.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, i don't know how i overlooked that, it's embarrassing :D

Comment: This is my favorite answer on SO. If I could give you more upvotes I would.

Comment: @JacobH maybe if you install SQL Server, your problem will get solved. :)